# The hv.Div() does not show the expected HTML code

Tags: html, bokeh, holoviews

I use a Div as follows:

```
html = '<h1>Thi is my title</h1>'
div = hv.Div(html)
```

but the result is

```
<div class="bk bk-clearfix" style="display: inline-block; width: 300px; height: 300px;">This is my title</div>
```

Any idea why? No header tag, but the title inside a stupid 300×300px div.

Comment: Could you share abit more of the code?

Answer (score 2):

I can replicate those results in a Jupyter notebook with:

```py
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension("bokeh")
html = '<h1>This is my <i>title</i></h1>'
hv.Div(html)
```

The 300x300 box is because a Div is meant to be used alongside other plots, each with a fixed (though sometimes responsive) size. You can add `.opts(height=100)` or `.opts(sizing_mode="...")` (with various options for `...`) to the div to control the sizing, though I haven't seen any option for "whatever size the content actually is".

In any case the missing markup is a bug in recent HoloViews releases, because Bokeh itself handles the markup just fine (see e.g. https://docs.bokeh.org/en/2.4.0/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#div), while HoloViews appears to be stripping out all the markup (https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Div.html). This has been reported as a bug in HoloViews (https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues/4743).